# PowerBI: Formatting totals on combined stacked bar & line graph

Tags: formatting, powerbi

I have a visualization (below) that is a combination Stack bar and Line graph . I am trying to format the data labels for the line graph totals- so that they all hover above the stacked bar. This works(with default settings) for all of the dates except the first bar (see image below- highlighted in yellow). There appears to be no formatting options available for the data labels of the line graph to control the label position (unlike in the stacked bar).

Any suggestions on how to force the totals to always appear above the bars?

A simple example file is available here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m4qicc5gv5fCmVPiBe2m6THuHGKjacnx/view?usp=sharing

Any suggestions appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Format > Y-Axis > Show secondary** and set it to the **Off** position and it should look like this:

[image: Single Axis]

What's happening is that your line and bars were on independent axes, which makes them align not how you intend.

Comment: This  works with the demo file- but not when I apply the same solution  to my actual production graph. Image : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yNj2HliKZ14ScLTmItUVc5QfQ6SRXl7D/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hmm. It looks like it's placing the label below the line rather than above it when there are troughs in the graph. Try putting the **Label density** for the line data labels to **100%**. I've seen that make a difference in positioning before.

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI supports **[Total labels for stacked visuals](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/pl-pl/blog/power-bi-september-2020-feature-summary/)**:

> You can now turn on total labels for your stacked bar/column, stacked area, and line and stacked column charts, allowing you to see the aggregates of your data at a glance

[image]